# What method can be used to find the approximate numerical solution of any transcendental equation?

Tags: functions

for example:

```
-(1/(1 + x)) + 2 Cos[x] - 2 Cos[2 x] == 0

2 Sin[x] - Sin[2 x] - Log[x + 1]==0
```

Use this method:

```
N@FindInstance[-(1/(1 + x)) + 2 Cos[x] - 2 Cos[2 x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

```
{{x -> 31.5174}}
```

The result calculated using the above method seems incorrect

[image]

How can we find the approximate numerical solution of any transcendental equation or the numerical approximate solution of a specified interval?

Comment: `FindInstance` is really more suitable for solving logical problems, exact solutions, stuff like that. You should really be using `FindRoot` or `NSolve`. You can also `NMinimize` the square of the left hand side in an equation of the form `expr == 0`. Also not sure why you think the answer is incorrect - it's clearly an approximate root. If you wanted others you need to add a number, or `All` at the end of your `FindInstance`, though `All` won't work since there seem to be infinitely many solutions.

Comment: See also [`ResourceFunction["BisectionMethodFindRoot"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BisectionMethodFindRoot/) .

Comment: NSolve,Unable to solve this equation using NSolve

Comment: Yeah NSolve doesn't work because it's unconstrained. If you add a constraint it works fine `NSolve[-(1/(1 + x)) + 2 Cos[x] - 2 Cos[2 x] == 0 && 0 < x < 5, x]` produces `{{x -> 0.497229}, {x -> 2.02952}, {x -> 4.22604}}`

Comment: How to use FindRoot to solve?

Comment: Look it up in the docs. Type `FindRoot`, and press the (i) or right click on it and choose `Get Help`. On this site you are expected to at least have made an effort to read the documentation first if you don't understand something. If you don't have the docs installed, [see here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

Comment: FindRoot[-(1/(1 + x)) + 2 Cos[x] - 2 Cos[2 x] == 0, {x, 2}]

Comment: expr1 = -(1/(1 + x)) + 2 Cos[x] - 2 Cos[2 x]
Solve[expr1 == 0 && -2 <= x <= 34, x] // N

Answer (score 2):

If you have a plot of your function you might get an approximate solution directly if you add some Mesh-options:
:

```
pic = Plot[-(1/(1 + x)) + 2 Cos[x] - 2 Cos[2 x], {x, -2, 5},MeshFunctions ->{#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}]
points = pic[[1]][[1, 1]] (* plotted points*)
index = Cases[pic, Point[p_] :> p, -1][[1]]

p0=points[[index]]
(*{{0.495286, 0.}, {2.02833, 0.}, {4.22782, 0.}}*)

Show[pic, Graphics[{Red, Point[p0]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) gives correct results. You did not plot in the vicinity of FindInstance's results nor constrain the solution to the region of the plot.

```
expr1 = -(1/(1 + x)) + 2 Cos[x] - 2 Cos[2 x];

sol1a = FindInstance[expr1 == 0, x, Reals, 5]
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions,

```
expr1 /. sol1a // FullSimplify

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

If you want solutions constrained to the region that you plotted,

```
sol1b = FindInstance[expr1 == 0 && -2 < x < 5, x, Reals, 5]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
expr1 /. sol1b // FullSimplify

(* {0, 0, 0} *)
```

Similarly, for the second expression,

```
expr2 = 2 Sin[x] - Sin[2 x] - Log[x + 1];

sol2a = FindInstance[expr2 == 0, x, Reals, 5]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
expr2 /. sol2a // FullSimplify

(* {0, 0, 0} *)
```

Constraining the results to an interval,

```
sol2b = FindInstance[expr2 == 0 && -1 < x < 10, x, Reals, 5]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
expr2 /. sol2b // FullSimplify

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: `FindInstance` is really the wrong tool here, as others have pointed out. Much better to use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), which is the tool to solve equations: `Solve[expr1 == 0 && -2 <= x <= 5, x]` for example.

Comment: @Roman - While it is not an approach that I would recommend generally, I was responding to the OP’s statement that the result using FindInstance was “incorrect”.

Comment: Bob, I understand and was aiming this comment at the OP, not at you. Quite generally, a lot of the questions asked here are [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and I find that very often it helps to take a step back from the OP's code and try to address the underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FindRoot[]` and discretize your search domain with a for loop (consider maybe `ParallelTable[]` if the original problem is highly time-consuming).

This following brute force solution could work if you are only interested in numerical approximations :

```
f[x_] = -(1/(1 + x)) + 2 Cos[x] - 2 Cos[2 x];
{xMin, xMax, di} = {0, 5, 0.5};
SOL = Table[x/.FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, i}], {i, xMin, xMax, di}]
```

Then consider removing the duplicates (according to a tolerance) by applying the following boolean operation :

```
Tol = 10^-5;
Union[SOL, SameTest -> (Abs[Norm@#1 - Norm@#2] < Tol &)]

(*{0.497229, 2.02952, 4.22604, 6.06376}*)
```